# Python Dataframe research function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a question for Python users (2.7). I have a Panda DataFrame with in the first column dates. For each date there is numbers corresponding to it in the same row.

ex .

14/12/1900      0.17    0.76    0.15    0.92

15/12/1900      0.64    0.78    0.78    0.04

16/12/1900      0.57    0.18    0.45    0.76

17/12/1900      0.53    0.15    0.89    0.22

etc...

I am trying to create a function or find a way to, when I enter the date, it gives me back all the corresponding row. (each dates are unique).

ex. 
[in] find_row('14/12/1900')

[out] 0.17  0.76    0.15    0.92

I am struggling with that, any idea? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Check the answer of this question I think it has what you are looking for:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank you!